# What happens if one filter throws Exceptions in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to add a filter to an existing project, and don't expect my filter to affect the original process in abnormal case. In any cases, the original filter should be executed.

So, I want to know, how should I process when I catch an Exception:

1. throw the Exception
2. catch the Exception and call `chain.doFilter();`
3. do nothing, like the following code:

   ```
   if (filter != null) {

       filter.doFilter(req,resp,chain);
       // should I catch the exception here?
   } else {

       chain.doFilter(req,resp);
   }
   ```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

nest your `try-catch` block inside `if(filter!=null)` 
For instance:

```
if(filter != null){
     try{} catch (Exception e){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Also you can use `finally` after `catch` for any clean up or code you want to run no whether an exception is caught or not.